# How to export each nested value as a separated file in MongoDb?

Tags: json, mongodb, export

I have this tree structure:

```
Document
|--_id: ObjectId(21346f7b7ada873)
|--a  : "valueA"
|--b  : "valueb"
|--c  :
|  |-- ca : "ca" 
|  |-- cb : "cb" 
|  |-- cc : {...}
|  |-- cd : [...]
|  |-- ce : {...}
|  |-- cf : {...}
.
.
.
```

Let's say I would want to export each value of "**c**" into a separate .json file like **ca.json, cb.json, cc.json**, etc. Is there a way to do it using native mongoDb functions?

Comment: You can export the whole document. And split it up from there using something like jq.

Answer (score 0):

you can use these commands:

```
  mongoexport -d [ --db ] -c [ --collection ] -f [ --fields ] -o    sample.json
  mongoexport --db <db> --collections <collection> --out sample.json
```